# Twig for loop "this"

Tags: twig

How can I use passed in data in a For-loop?

I would like to do something like this:
(Using "this" doesn't work)

```
{% for button in this %}
    Button in passed in array        
{% endfor %}
```

*** EDIT ***

I have a twig-template called button-group, where I have a loop that loops through all the buttons passed into the twig-template. But I can't loop through any data I pass in.

**My embed:**

```
{% if data.buttons %}
  {% embed "button-group.twig" data.buttons %}{% endembed %}
{% endif %}
```

**Button-group.twig:**

```
{% for button in this %} {# this should be the same as passed data.buttons #}
  <button>{{buttonText}}</button>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: What should `this` reference to? What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I've edited the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All variables are available in the embedded file. You can simply iterate over `data.buttons` like:

```
{# button-group.html.twig #}
{% for button in data.buttons %}
    <button>{{ buttonText }}</button>
{% endfor %}
```

You can however pass the variable explicitly under a different name:

```
{# skeleton.html.twig #}
{% embed "default/test.html.twig" with {buttons: data.buttons} only %}{% endembed %}

{# button-group.html.twig #}
{% for button in buttons %}
    <button>{{ buttonText }}</button>
{% endfor %}
```

The keyword `only` implies that only the passed variables will be available in the embedded template. If omitted you could use either `buttons` or `data.buttons` in *button-group.html.twig*.

**Further reading**

- [Twig documentation: `embed`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/embed.html)

---

**Note**: I can't find any reference to an automatically generated variable `this` in the Twig manual for "[*`embed`*](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/embed.html)". You could of course embed the template with `{this: data.buttons}` and create it yourself. I would not recommend using this variable name, as it can be confusing with PHP's `$this`, which on the other hand can't be re-assigend.

---

**Another note**: In your loop you output a variable named `buttonText` which is not defined in your example. You may need to change that to something like `button` or `button.text` according on whatever `data-buttons` hold.

Comment: Great. Thanks! Just what I needed! :-)